# Differences between groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, group-differences

I am currently doing a research on effects of writing styles on the perception of reader.

Currently I have the following 4 groups

```
Group 1: Pre Test - Treatment 1a - Post Test
Group 2: Pre Test - Treatment 1b - Post Test
Group 3: Pre Test - Treatment 2a - Post Test
Group 4: Pre Test - Treatment 2b - Post Test

Treatment 1 refers to a normal writing style and Treatment 2 refers to the enhanced writing style.
```

I understand the most researchers will assume that pretest for all 4 groups are the same due to randomly chosen participants. However, what it can show is only that the treatments influence the participants.

Is there any statistical tests I can use to test that treatment 1 influences the participants more than treatment 2?

Thank you! any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a control group?

Comment: Treatment 1 is the control group.

Comment: What do the small a and b refer to? Any reason why the methods discussed in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs do not apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use ANOVA with orthogonal contrasts. In this case, this would be an example of "planned multiple comparisons". See http://web.uct.ac.za/depts/psychology/psy400w/stats/anova/multcomp.pdf

Comment: Hmm. a question. Do i take the difference between pre test and post test as the "sum" in the example given in the link? thank you.

Comment: Will you do calculations by hand or are you using any particular software (SPSS, Excel, R)? It would make things easier to explain.

Comment: You need to calculate one sum for each treatment. You then apply the contrast on these sums.

Comment: I am using SPSS.

Comment: I hope this helps: http://www.statisticshell.com/docs/contrasts.pdf

Comment: hi @daniel Labbe, just another question. Is the "libido" in the example equivalent to the difference in perception in pretest and posttest in mine?